# Are there any resources for determining whether a given name is more likely to be male or female?

Tags: discussion, resources

I'm looking for some kind of resource in which I can lookup a given name (either in hiragana or kanji) and find out whether the name is more likely to belong to a person who is either male or female.

I know that this can't be done unambiguously since some names are fairly evenly used for both genders, but for some names like e.g. 次郎{じ.ろう} or かなこ, I would expect this resource to tell me that the former name is predominantly used by males, and the latter predominantly by females.

For reference, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/818231/1535629) on SO contains a link to a resource that is probably the English equivalent of what I'm looking for (except that I can't access it to make sure, because the US government is down at the moment).

Comment: I migrated this question to meta instead of closing because the community seems to agree we should allow some resource questions on meta.

Comment: (Sorry, @istrasci, it automatically deleted your comment when I migrated because it linked to meta!)

Comment: Rather than a formal resource, Google and Google Images usually give pretty good indications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WWWJDIC](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1C) uses a special version of ENAMDICT which merges entries for the same kanji and sorts readings by approximate frequency order.  Given name results are tagged (f) for female, (m) for male, and (g) for given name not yet classified ([see ENAMDICT docs here](ftp://ftp.edrdg.org/pub/Nihongo/enamdict_doc.html)).

You can also download ENAMDICT, but it might be less useful in its regular version.  But [Jim Breen posted in sci.lang.japan](http://sci.tech-archive.net/Archive/sci.lang.japan/2013-03/msg00040.html) that someone was "welcome to a copy of that file", so perhaps he would be willing to share it if you emailed him.